# How to use OAuth 2.0 in Oracle Application Express?

Tags: oracle, web-services, rest, security, oauth

I have created an application that calling Oracle RESTful Webservice. But I want to add OAuth 2.0 when calling this webservice in order to maintain the security of the data. I have follow the tutorial ['Accessing the RESTful Services from a Third Party Application'](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html#securing_the_gallery_restful_services)

But when I try to get the access token, I got the error below
https://server:port/i/oauthdemo/gallery.html#error=access_denied&state=STATE

In this document got mention, this error happen if user denies the request.
Can anyone help me how to approve the request?Is there any extra configuration that I need make?